# Ordering of require() seems to affect modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, require

I'm writing a very basic Node app with three components: index.js, mqtt.js, slack.js. The mqtt and slack modules both expose some of their methods with module.exports. However, I can only expose the files in one direction. Code sample:

index.js:

```
var slack = require('./slack');
var mqtt = require('./mqtt');

var client;

mqtt.connectMQTT(client);
slack.startServer();
```

slack.js:

```
var mqtt = require('./mqtt');
module.exports = {
startServer: function() { //blahblah },
postToSlack: function() { //blahblah }
};
```

mqtt.js:

```
var slack = require('./slack');
module.exports = {
connectClient: function() { //blahblah },
handleMessage: function() { slack.postToSlack(); }
};
```

Now, when I try to call postToSlack() from mqtt.js, Node gives me: TypeError: Object # has no method 'postToSlack'

BUT, when I swap the line position of the two require()'s in index.js, now I can call methods from mqtt but not from slack. The error has mirrored itself. I can call methods from index.js just fine.

Should I be using callbacks to hold off running any code until all of my modules have successfully been loaded? Why does the order of require() in a completely separate file affect exposing methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a circular dependency between `slack.js` and `mqtt.js`. Read [the node.js docs on require cycles](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#all_cycles) for details, but the correct solution to this situation is usually to remove the circular dependency entirely. It is an indicator that your design coupling is not quite right yet.